# How to redirect users to a subdomain based on his/her current location?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, geolocation

I am using Rails 3.1.1 and I would like to redirect users, for example, from the U.S.A. to a proper subdomain `us.site.com` (this one is hosted on the same server as `site.com`). I know that I can localize a user by his/her IP address but how can I do that so to redirect he/she to the proper subdomain? There is a technique/gem to geo-locate user IPs and then handle redirection?

*P.S.*: Maybe, for performance reasons, I should use middlewares...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://rubygems.org/gems/rack-geoipcity is a rack middleware gem I've published which you could use, or just use the GeoIP gem in your controllers.

With the rack-geoipcity, you would query the X-headers it adds in and make a decision based on that. Something like:

```
if headers['X_GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE'] == "IN"
  redirect "/india"
end
```

though I don't currently use Rails, so it might be slightly different.

[There are plenty to choose from](https://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=geoip) if you don't fancy using the MaxMind db.

Answer (score 1):

One approach that I've used happily in the past is to perform the geolocation lookup via DNS *before* users connect to the service; this way, they automatically connect to the server nearest them, you get cheap and easy load balancing and ability to remove servers from active use as you need, and individual sites can go down without influencing other sites.

OFTC uses a self-written [oftcdns](http://trac.oftc.net/projects/oftc-tools/browser/trunk/oftcdns/README) tool to provide users with nearest servers. During the time I was an administrator on the OFTC network, this tool was a drastic improvement over running a simpler Bind-based DNS server that did not provide geo-location features and complicated bringing servers in and out of the rotation.

Wikipedia uses [PowerDNS with a geobackend](http://wiki.powerdns.com/trac/browser/trunk/pdns/modules/geobackend/README) to provide their geo-ip services. PowerDNS is definitely well-tested, high-demand-capable tool.

Comment: Simply, I would like to redirect users to a subdomain hosted on the same server of the main domain. Maybe your solution is to "advanced" for my needs...

Comment: @sarnold +1, this looks really interesting.

Comment: @Iain: it definitely solves a problem that is difficult to solve in other fashions but your Rack middleware looks like a _much_ better fit for Backo. :)